# Jquery button 'click()' function not working to add new html text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, click

I"m trying to figure out why this function doesn't execute when it's called in the

```
 $(document).ready(function() : 

function sayQuote() { 
    $('#button').click($('#quotebox').html(function() { 
        var getQuote = quotes[randomNum];
        return getQuote;      
    });
    );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    sayQuote();
});
```

The console is saying there's a ')' missing after my arguments, but I can't determine where I need another one.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
 function sayQuote() 
 { 
      $('#button').click(function(){
           $('#quotebox').html(function(){ 
                var getQuote = quotes[randomNum];
                return getQuote;      
           });
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to put button click handler inside a function it could be like that

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#quotebox').html(quotes[randomNum]);
});
```

if you want to call this event by code you could use

```
$("#button").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to over complicate things.

```
function sayQuote() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var getQuote = quotes[randomNum];
        $('#quotebox').html(getQuote);
    });
}

$(document).ready(sayQuote);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define a function inside `.html()` method of jquery which does not make sense the correct approach to achieve the solution will be like this.

```
function sayQuote() { 
$('#button').click(function(){
  var getQuote = quotes[random];
  $('#quotebox').html(getQuote);
});
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    sayQuote();
});
```